# Pushing app-specific configurations (Plist) by apple configurator 2?

Tags: push, plist, mdm, configuration-profile, apple-configurator

Is it possible to push managed app configuration (I mean sending to an app a plist) by apple configurator 2 ? Maybe by using Configuration Profile Key? As far as I know this is possible by using MDM servers. Here are some examples of those http://simplemdm.com/2016/03/14/how-to-enroll-in-mdm-with-apple-configurator-2/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't possible to push Managed App Config via Apple Configurator 2 (AC2) as of version 2.7. AC2 isn't an MDM, and there are no options in AC2 to do this.

Your link [Managed App Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html) indicates this when it says the following:

> This functionality allows a Mobile Device Management (MDM) server to push down a dictionary into the managed app's NSUserDefaults for the purposes of remotely configuring settings.

The [Mobile Device Management Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH3-SW68) also mentions the following regarding Managed App Config:

> In iOS 7 and later, an MDM server can use configuration and feedback dictionaries to communicate with and configure third-party managed apps.

Neither of these references explicitly mention that AC2 cannot push Managed App Config, but the [Apple Configuration Profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf), which defines the profile configurations pushable by AC2, has no mention of Managed App Config.